# mongorestore always returns connection error

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

I have successfully performed a mongodump command of my Heroku server with an mLab database.
This is the code i used:

```
mongodump --host <thehost> -d <thedb> -u <username> -p <password>
--port 27175
```

The dump completed successfully.

Now i am trying to restore this dump on my local server, but no luck.
This error shows

```
 Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

Restoration Codes That I Have Tried:

```
mongorestore --db newdb /path/todump/file

mongorestore --db newdb

mongorestore  /path/todump/file

mongorestore --db newdb (run it inside the dump folder)

--host mongodb://[server-ip] --port [running-port] --db newdb /path/to/dump
```

I have also tried running in from my mac.
i performed the dump on my personal computer. 
And then ran.

```
mongorestore --host mongodb://[server-real-ip] --port [running-port] --db newdb /path/to/dump
```

Also the weird thing i that performing [mongo] locally or via the internet gives me access to the shell successfully without any error.

```
mongo --host mongodb://[server-real-ip] --port [running-port]
```

I searched every where, and tried almost every possible solution i could find.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Where you are running mongod... On local or on server?

Comment: Have you tried just giving the host name or ip address, without the _mongodb://_ prefix?

Comment: mongod is running on my server.

Comment: @VinceBowdren yes that was my mistake. thank you, it worked now

Comment: Great stuff, I'll post that as an Answer then.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is just trying out and might make a more careless error than this, 
I had included the database name in the host input, while leaving the database flag there too. So just make sure the host and database are specified accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Mongorestore should work if you give it just the host name or ip address, without the *mongodb://* prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If your Mongo DB is arranged as a replica set, you must use the PRIMARY node as the --host.

To determine which of your nodes is the primary, connect to any of the nodes using the mongo client and get the replica-set status.

```
rs.status()
...
"members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongo-00.node.cdvr:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
...
```